# What site can i compile and test C code online like codepad. Requirement:must be able to use 'scanf' properly

Tags: c

I am a student and want to test my amerature C code online at any computer. There is a fantastic website www.codepad.org that i use. My only problem is that it wont let me input things using scanf and it wont let me -lm. Is there a website that allows these things?

Comment: How about google `online ide`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then why don't you get a [free shell account](http://freeshell.org/)? So long as you are active, and don't break the rules, it's there for you.

Google for lots of other choices, if your provider goes up and down. Use [git](http://git-scm.com/) to keep a local copy of your code synchronized between all of your different shell accts and provide a backup. You can even push to [github](https://github.com).

This will also give you the opportunity to use and learn about a bunch of useful and important tools:

- ssh/mosh
- vim/emacs
- bash (don't forget process control!)
- gdb or cgdb
- tmux/screen
- python/perl/shell scripts
- make

I wish that my college classes had gone over at least some of these before I finished my degree...

Answer (score 2):

You can use scanf on [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/F4xtI), however I'm not sure about `-lm`.

That said, I can't recommend it for serious work.

Answer (score 2):

**[Ideone.com](http://ideone.com/)** allows you to give input.

Answer (score 1):

Many online compilers have one or the other limitation and the chances for debugging is remote. So I suggest you go for a complete linux machine, **online**!

Try [ubuntu on the cloud](https://try.cloud.ubuntu.com/). All your gcc, gdb etc are at your disposal just like your normal desktop.

**PS**: 1 hour limitation per account and you need to SSH without a GUI. But still worth it as it gives all the features a standard linux distro gives you, online!